# Why is my SpringLayout different from the example?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, springlayout

I am doing [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringDemo2Project/src/layout/SpringDemo2.java) example. My code is exactly the same but in stead of getting
 [image: This]

I am getting

[image: This]

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Uh...those are way different. Are you sure you have the right example? And `spring` isn't the right tag for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are running a different project. Next to the run button there is a drop down arrow, click it and pick the right project to run.

Comment: You are right. Im not sure which project I was running. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as correct so other users may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You're either joking or you're executing the wrong example. The linked code does definetly not create the second screenshot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are running a separate project within eclipse. Make sure that the project you are building and executing is the one that contains a textbox, instead of the tree structure shown.